# External SSD drive not detected as SSD drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-disk

I've got a Sandisk Extreme SSD drive as an external drive for my MacBook Pro. It has no problems with connecting to the MacBook or being recognized as an external drive.

The problem is it is not recognized as SSD drive.

[image: Extreme SSD Disk Info]

Here is the speed test result by Blackmagic Disk Speed Test app:

[image: ExtremeSSD - monitor USB hub]

Attached directly to MacBook:

[image: ExtremeSSD - included USB-C cable]

To compare, default drive:

[image: ExtremeSSD - included USB-C cable]

Where should I look for an issue? I'm using the monitor USB hub as a connector, could it be an issue? Or any other adapter?

No matter if I connect drive through an adapter or Thunderbolt port, it is not recognized as SSD drive.

How to make macOS to see this drive as SSD and run with better speed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the make and model of your MacBook? What is the version of macOS that you are running? Are you using the SSD inside an enclosure or connecting it directly? What port are you connecting the SSD to? What's the make and model of your external SSD?

Comment: I don't think the speed you get is dependent on whether the Mac knows the drive is an SSD. The internal storage interface is always going to be faster than an external one, as far as I know. Whether an external drive is recognised as an SSD is probably down to whether the interface chipset in your USB-to-SSD adapter/enclosure supports this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the monitor USB hub as a connector, could it be an issue?

Yes, that's probably the problem. Based on the speeds you're seeing, I suspect that the USB hub in the monitor is a USB2 device; connecting your drive through that hub is slowing down the connection to USB2 speeds.

Connect the SSD directly to your computer, or use an external USB3 hub.

Comment: Even when I connect the drive directly to the computer with the cable from SanDisk it doesn't recognize it as SSD :(